# CircleCI - Log Irregular Failures

Tags: circleci

CircleCI runs my tests three times, and the build passes if all tests pass at least once. Recently I've been trying to track down and deal with irregular test failures (non-deterministic tests), and I would like to have an easy record of which tests have failed, then passed, during a build, along with links to those builds and their artifacts.

Is there a way to log these irregular failures on CircleCI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which test runner are you using?

If it’s RSpec, you could try using [rspec-rerun gem](https://github.com/dblock/rspec-rerun) and parse its results, or access RSpec’s run time information for failed test names.

CircleCI doesn’t have built-in support for the record of failing tests you mention:

> an easy record of which tests have failed, then passed, during a build, along with links to those builds and their artifacts.

But you could take a look at the [CircleCI API](http://circleci.com/docs/api), maybe you can use it to automate this workflow.

Comment: It is RSpec. Thanks, I'll take a look at the CircleCI API and see what it offers.

Comment: CircleCI API is indeed the way to do this. Thanks!